# Embedded UINavigationController's back button does not work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uicontainerview

I'm using a `Container View` control through interface builder to embedded a `UINavigationController` and its stack into my app.

The problem I'm having is that the back button does not work on all pushed VCs over the Root VC.

You press the automatically generated back button on these pushed VCs and nothing happens.

**Edit:**

There is no code written. Its all set up in IB at the moment.

[image]

As you can see...Container View with its embedded view controller set to the UInavigation Controller. The whitespace on the left will be a swipeable menu eventually - thats the reason for the set up. Then there's a next button on the root RV which segues to a second view controller.

[image]

That state is shown above. Pressing the back button (labelled test) does nothing. Normally it would pop the top view controller and go back to 'test'. Clearly the embedding is interfering with the normal UINavigiationController function somehow.

I just dont know how.

**Another Edit:**

Making a custom button on that top View Controller and manually calling

```
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

Actually works and the top view controller is removed from the stack.

So the question is why does the back button not work?

Comment: There's no code, its all IB. I added screenshots.

Comment: I made the same setup as you show in your question, and the back button worked just fine. You might try cleaning your project, closing and reopening Xcode, or making a new project, and see if it works.

Comment: You're absolutely right, starting from scratch: it does work. My project is already quite advanced though, so starting over is not an option! I tried doing a clean but that doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I could have done wrong to make it stop working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I forgot that I added a tap gesture recognizer to my navigation bar. The back button actually received touches (pushed state) but as in your example did nothing. A custom button on the navigation bar worked though.
Once I removed the gesture recognizer the back button worked again.

Maybe some other view/or gesture recognizer in your container view is catching the touches...

Comment: Thanks for the comment; you're absolutely right, removing a tap gesture recognizer has allowed the back button to work. The only remaining problem is that it only goes back on the navigation bar (ie. loads the previous navigation item) - it doesn't, however, pop the top most view controller! Did yours go back to working properly once you removed the gesture recogniser?

Comment: Yeah... on first view controller i added tap on navigationBar and on next VC BackButton doesn't work. Thx for your answer :)

Comment: did you tried tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false ?